Difference between Vid and Vidr
I have two different operational amplifiers datasheets with absolute maximum ratings. The TI LM358DR has a differential input voltage specification (Vid) of -32 V to 32 V, whereas the OnSemi LM358DR2G has an input differential voltage range specification (Vidr) of ±32 Vdc. What do these specifications mean and how are they different?

These are exactly the same parameters/specifications. And there is no difference between these two voltages (Vid and Vidr). So it is the maximum difference in voltage that the input transistors can withstand without damage.  But this 32V looks really suspicious.

@G36 What is suspicious about 32 V? It is also the supply voltage limit.

Thanks. I have reason to believe that the specifications are different, because one component often gets damaged during power-up (transients) and the other never.
